# Is JSON.parse supposed to be recursive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am parsing a json string like so:

```
ring = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now, `ring` is an object but ring.stones is just a string when it should be an object as well.

If I call:

```
ring.stones = JSON.parse(ring.stones);
```

It is now the correct object.

I didn't know if this is correct behavior or if maybe I have an issue somewhere stopping it from parsing recursively? If it is supposed to parse recursively, are there any known issues that would prevent it?

---

#### Update

Here is the full response before parsing:

{"ring_id":"9","stone_count":"4","style_number":"style 4","syn10":"436.15","gen10":"489.39","syn14":"627.60","gen14":"680.85","available":"yes","type":"ring","engravings_count":"0","engravings_char_count":"0","engravings_band":"10","stones":"[{\"stone_id\":\"27\",\"ring_id\":\"9\",\"stone_shape\":\"round\",\"stone_x\":\"132.80\",\"stone_y\":\"114.50\",\"stone_width\":\"71.60\",\"stone_height\":\"71.60\",\"stone_rotation\":\"0.00\",\"stone_number\":\"1\",\"stone_mm_width\":\"5.00\",\"stone_mm_height\":\"5.00\"},{\"stone_id\":\"28\",\"ring_id\":\"9\",\"stone_shape\":\"round\",\"stone_x\":\"100.50\",\"stone_y\":\"166.20\",\"stone_width\":\"36.20\",\"stone_height\":\"36.60\",\"stone_rotation\":\"0.00\",\"stone_number\":\"2\",\"stone_mm_width\":\"2.50\",\"stone_mm_height\":\"2.50\"},{\"stone_id\":\"29\",\"ring_id\":\"9\",\"stone_shape\":\"round\",\"stone_x\":\"200.20\",\"stone_y\":\"105.10\",\"stone_width\":\"33.90\",\"stone_height\":\"33.90\",\"stone_rotation\":\"0.00\",\"stone_number\":\"3\",\"stone_mm_width\":\"2.50\",\"stone_mm_height\":\"2.50\"},{\"stone_id\":\"30\",\"ring_id\":\"9\",\"stone_shape\":\"round\",\"stone_x\":\"165.80\",\"stone_y\":\"82.50\",\"stone_width\":\"35.50\",\"stone_height\":\"33.90\",\"stone_rotation\":\"0.00\",\"stone_number\":\"4\",\"stone_mm_width\":\"2.50\",\"stone_mm_height\":\"2.50\"}]","images":"[{\"title\":\"white gold\",\"source\":\"Style4_4_W_M.png\"},{\"title\":\"yellow gold\",\"source\":\"Style4_4_Y_M.png\"}]"}

---

#### Update 2

Based on mikerobi's answer I was able to figure out what was happening:

Here is where I encoded it:

```
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$row['stones'] = getStones($ring_id);
$row['images'] = getRingVariations($ring_id);

return json_encode($row);
```

But the functions `getStones` and `getRingVariations` were returning `json_encode`'d strings. I needed to change them to return plain strings.

Comment: How does `response` look like?

Comment: @KennyTM @dlamblin I updated my answer to show the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON structure is wrong, it is wrapping stones in quotes, turning it into a string.

Your JSON looks like:

```
{
    stones: "[{\"stone_id":\"27\"},{\"stone_id\":\"27\"}]"
}
```

It should look like:

```
{
    stones: [{"stone_id": 27},{"stone_id": 27}]
}
```

**EDIT**

It appears you are converting all values to string, including numbers, I updated my example to reflect this.

Also, I'm guessing by the output that you are writing your own code to serialize the JSON, I highly recommend using an existing library.

Comment: Thanks, I was using PHP's built in JSON encoder, but after refactoring it I was mistakingly parsing them twice. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

It is recursive, but your input string (`response`) is not in correct format. Get rid of those escape characters (`\"`) and try again.

Comment: And the quotes around the whole stones value.